# Replace number with sequential ID in SED

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have around 12k files with a string like this:

`script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.391810");`

I need to change the last 6 digits (391810) to a sequential ID starting on 300000. So far I have done this:

```
`find . -type f -name '*.nasl' -exec sed -i -e 's/script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.\(.*\)/script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.\1/g' {} \;`
```

I have been trying some ideas with AWK but so far I don't find the solution. So, I need help here. I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Comment: If you want to modify multiple lines then post a [mcve] (including input AND output) with multiple lines so we have something that helps demonstrate your requirements and we can test a potential solution against. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, I don't want to modify multiple lines, only the string that I mentioned on my post `script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.391810");` which is a single line on more than 12k files. I want to change the last 6 digits in the string (1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.391810 - the last 6 would be 391810) to a sequential number starting on 300000. I was trying SED, but as I said on my post I need some help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you do want to modify multiple lines, they're just spread across multiple files. So show that as the [mcve]. Say 3 files with that line in context in each file along with some small number of truly representative other lines or surrounding text on the same lines that you don't want modified. If it really is just 1 line in 1 file then just use `vi`.

Comment: @EdMorton: No, I don't want to modify multiple lines. Only one (1) single line on more than 12,000 files. That line that I need to modify is `script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.391810");`.

Comment: When the script is done more than 1 line will have been modified so that sounds like multiple to me but however you want to say it... create a [mcve] that demonstrates your requirements and we can test against if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: @EdMorton: Just to let you know that tshiono's answer is perfect and it solved the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for the followup. It will fail in various ways given various possible input file contents (for example it's not escaping the `.`s in the regexp so they'll match any char, not just the strings you're trying to match), it has unnecessary redundancy (a capture group around the fixed part of the string + backrefernce would be better) and it's extremely inefficient (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) but that's great that you're happy with the one answer you got and I'm sorry if you felt like I was trying to do anything other than help you with my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
id=300000
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    sed  -e "s/script_oid(\"1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.7.0.\(.*\)/script_oid(\"1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.$id/g" "$f"
    id=$((++id))
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.nasl' -print0)
```

Note that the `id` is assigned in the order of appearance by `find`.